# Implement "through" in already existent ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I'm dealing with this complex scenario, and I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

**Context**:

I have this situation:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
   treats = models.ManyToManyFields(Treat)

class Treat(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
```

This relation is a legacy one, there's already data in production.

**Problem**:

A new restriction has come up, in which the `Treat` model has to be moved to a new database.
That means, in short, I have to separate the constraint with treats from cat.

**Proposal**:

I've been told that, given my scenario, I have no choice but to implement a custom intermediate model to preserve the m2m but to also allow for the `db_constraint=False`. The suggestion was something like:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
   treats = models.ManyToManyFields(Treat, through=CatTreat, related_name="cats")

class Treat(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class CatTreat(models.Model):
   cat = models.ForeignKey(Cat)
   treat = models.ForeignKey(Treat, db_constraint=False)
```

In my local stack, after running the migrations I've found myself that I can't access the data.

```
from apps.animals.models import Cat

cat = Cat.objects.first()
cat.treats
# => animals.Treat.None
cat.treats.through.objects.all()
# => <Queryset []>
```

I'm not sure if the new through access is not configured correctly or if I have inadvertently delete my data. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a little more configuration was needed.

In the through table, this was missing:

```
class CatTreat(models.Model):
   cat = models.ForeignKey(Cat)
   treat = models.ForeignKey(Treat, db_constraint=False)
  
   class Meta:
     db_column = "table_name"


cat.treats.all()
# => [...]
```

and that was it! I had to run the migration as fake though, in order to not lose any data.